# Python: Elegantly merge dictionaries with sum() of values

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to merge logs from several servers. Each log is a list of tuples (`date`, `count`). `date` may appear more than once, and I want the resulting dictionary to hold the sum of all counts from all servers.

Here's my attempt, with some data for example:

```python
from collections import defaultdict

a=[("13.5",100)]
b=[("14.5",100), ("15.5", 100)]
c=[("15.5",100), ("16.5", 100)]
input=[a,b,c]

output=defaultdict(int)
for d in input:
        for item in d:
           output[item[0]]+=item[1]
print dict(output)
```

Which gives:

```
{'14.5': 100, '16.5': 100, '13.5': 100, '15.5': 200}
```

As expected.

**I'm about to go bananas because of a colleague who saw the code. She insists that there must be a more Pythonic and elegant way to do it, without these nested for loops. Any ideas?**

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: `Counter()` only counts occurences, and as the values are already pre-populated it will not work for this scenario.

Comment: @ChristianWitts see my solution below.

Comment: What seems unpythonic to me is spending time worrying about making perfectly clear code more pythonic.  The Pythonicness which needs hours of thought is not the true Pythonicness.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: You learn something new every day :)

Comment: unnecessary 1-liner (deserves complaints, unlike your code): `dict([(k, sum([v2 for k2,v2 in a+b+c if k2==k])) for k,v in a+b+c])`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Doesn't get simpler than this, I think:

```
a=[("13.5",100)]
b=[("14.5",100), ("15.5", 100)]
c=[("15.5",100), ("16.5", 100)]
input=[a,b,c]

from collections import Counter

print sum(
    (Counter(dict(x)) for x in input),
    Counter())
```

Note that `Counter` (also known as a multiset) is the most natural data structure for your data (a type of set to which elements can belong more than once, or equivalently - a map with semantics Element -> OccurrenceCount. You could have used it in the first place, instead of lists of tuples.

---

Also possible:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import add

print reduce(add, (Counter(dict(x)) for x in input))
```

Using `reduce(add, seq)` instead of `sum(seq, initialValue)` is generally more flexible and allows you to skip passing the redundant initial value.

Note that you could also use `operator.and_` to find the intersection of the multisets instead of the sum.

---

The above variant is terribly slow, because a new Counter is created on every step. Let's fix that.

We know that `Counter+Counter` returns a new `Counter` with merged data. This is OK, but we want to avoid extra creation. Let's use `Counter.update` instead:

> update(self, iterable=None, **kwds) unbound collections.Counter method
>
> Like dict.update() but add counts instead of replacing them.
>   Source can be an iterable, a dictionary, or another Counter instance.

That's what we want. Let's wrap it with a function compatible with `reduce` and see what happens.

```
def updateInPlace(a,b):
    a.update(b)
    return a

print reduce(updateInPlace, (Counter(dict(x)) for x in input))
```

This is only marginally slower than the OP's solution.

**Benchmark**: http://ideone.com/7IzSx *(Updated with yet another solution, thanks to **astynax**)*

*(Also: If you desperately want an one-liner, you can replace `updateInPlace` by `lambda x,y: x.update(y) or x` which works the same way and even proves to be a split second faster, but fails at readability. Don't :-))*

Comment: What about time complexity? Is it more efficient than OP's code

Comment: I don't think so. The OP's code doesn't create any immediate objects, so it should generally be more efficient.

Comment: This approach is indeed the slowest of what was presented here, with OP's original solution being the fastest. No surprises here. http://ideone.com/HAmvi

Comment: Fixed with a more efficient approach. Benchmark: http://ideone.com/2eGQi

Comment: +1 That's truly elegant. Thanks for presenting this data structure - it fits the problem like a glove; Plus there is not enough data to care about performance.

Comment: @Kos, i slightly changed the [benchmark](http://ideone.com/7IzSx). Fastest way: `defaultdict` + `chain` (and my rewrited `merge_with` in the middle) :)

Answer (score 11):

```
from collections import Counter


a = [("13.5",100)]
b = [("14.5",100), ("15.5", 100)]
c = [("15.5",100), ("16.5", 100)]

inp = [dict(x) for x in (a,b,c)]
count = Counter()
for y in inp:
  count += Counter(y)
print(count)
```

**output:**

```
Counter({'15.5': 200, '14.5': 100, '16.5': 100, '13.5': 100})
```

**Edit:**
As [duncan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107660/duncan) suggested you can replace these 3 lines with a single line:

```
   count = Counter()
    for y in inp:
      count += Counter(y)
```

replace by : `count = sum((Counter(y) for y in inp), Counter())`

Comment: You could even remove the `for` loop by using `sum`: `count = sum((Counter(y) for y in inp), Counter())`

Comment: @Duncan thanks's I never knew that, suggestion implemented.

Comment: Or just `count = sum(inp, Counter())` if they're already Counters. :D

Answer (score 7):

You could use itertools' [groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

a=[("13.5",100)]
b=[("14.5",100), ("15.5", 100)]
c=[("15.5",100), ("16.5", 100)]
input = sorted(chain(a,b,c), key=lambda x: x[0])

output = {}
for k, g in groupby(input, key=lambda x: x[0]):
  output[k] = sum(x[1] for x in g)

print output
```

The use of `groupby` instead of two loops and a `defaultdict` will make your code clearer.

Comment: instead of the lambda, you can also drop in an `operator.itemgetter(0)` :)

Comment: Wrong: `groupby`, as said in the doc you mention, needs sorting first ! Here this works because `b[1]` and `c[0]` will be consecutive in `chain(a,b,c)` but if you do `chain(a,c,b)` instead, the result is not correct (you get 100 instead of 200 for `output['15.5']`)...

Comment: I guess its personal taste, but I find this harder to read than defaultdict, and also its slower than the OP approach

Comment: You're welcome, good to have thought about `groupby` anyway !

Comment: @Emmanuel Yeah, it just seemed natural to use it. But also I think there's nothing wrong with the code the questioneer uses. As fraxel said: a matter of personal taste in the end.

Comment: BTW This is sub-optimal because it needs to have all the input sequences in memory at once **and** needs to sort the whole chain of them.

Comment: Hah, profiling ftw. I said sub-optimal, but still faster than mine. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Counter or defaultdict, or you can try my variant:

```
def merge_with(d1, d2, fn=lambda x, y: x + y):
    res = d1.copy() # "= dict(d1)" for lists of tuples
    for key, val in d2.items(): # ".. in d2" for lists of tuples
        try:
            res[key] = fn(res[key], val)
        except KeyError:
            res[key] = val
    return res

>>> merge_with({'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'c':4})
{'a': 4, 'c': 4, 'b': 2}
```

Or even more generic:

```
def make_merger(fappend=lambda x, y: x + y, fempty=lambda x: x):
    def inner(*dicts):
        res = dict((k, fempty(v)) for k, v
            in dicts[0].items()) # ".. in dicts[0]" for lists of tuples
        for dic in dicts[1:]:
            for key, val in dic.items(): # ".. in dic" for lists of tuples
                try:
                    res[key] = fappend(res[key], val)
                except KeyError:
                    res[key] = fempty(val)
        return res
    return inner

>>> make_merger()({'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'c':4})
{'a': 4, 'c': 4, 'b': 2}

>>> appender = make_merger(lambda x, y: x + [y], lambda x: [x])
>>> appender({'a':1, 'b':2}, {'a':3, 'c':4}, {'b':'BBB', 'c':'CCC'})
{'a': [1, 3], 'c': [4, 'CCC'], 'b': [2, 'BBB']}
```

Also you can subclass the `dict` and implement a `__add__` method: