# Summing dictionaries in a large dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

What would be the most efficient way to sum across dictionaries within a large dictionary in Python?

I am finding similar posts, but not exactly what I am looking for. For example, there is a post for dict in a list: [Python: Elegantly merge dictionaries with sum() of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11290092/python-elegantly-merge-dictionaries-with-sum-of-values). There are other stuffs too, but not exactly for dict within a dict.

Example code would be:

```
a={}
a["hello"]={'n': 1,'m': 2,'o': 3}
a["bye"]={'n': 2,'m': 1,'o': 0}
a["goodbye"]={'n': 0,'m': 2,'o': 1}
```

And the output I need would be:

```
{'n': 3,'m': 5,'o': 4}
```

Please, help! Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
>>> a = {}
>>> a["hello"]={'n': 1,'m': 2,'o': 3}
>>> a["bye"]={'n': 2,'m': 1,'o': 0}
>>> a["goodbye"]={'n': 0,'m': 2,'o': 1}
>>> import collections
>>> result = collections.Counter()
>>> for d in a.values():
...     result += collections.Counter(d)
...
>>> result
Counter({'m': 5, 'o': 4, 'n': 3})
>>> dict(result)
{'m': 5, 'o': 4, 'n': 3}
```

---

Using `collections.Counter` with [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) (similar to the answer in the link you provided):

```
>>> a = ...
>>> sum(map(collections.Counter, a.values()), collections.Counter())
Counter({'m': 5, 'o': 4, 'n': 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> a = {'bye': {'m': 1, 'o': 0, 'n': 2}, 'hello': {'m': 2, 'o': 3, 'n': 1}, 'goodbye': {'m': 2, 'o': 1, 'n': 0}}
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for v in a.values():                                              
...     for x, y in v.iteritems():                                              
...             d[x] += y
... 
>>> print d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'m': 5, 'o': 4, 'n': 3})
```