# Merge two lists together

Tags: python, merge

I have two lists in python:

```
L1=[[100, 1], [101, 2]]
L2=[[100, 3], [101, 4], [102, 5]]
```

and I want to merge them so I get:

```
L_merge=[[100, 4], [101, 6], [102, 5]]
```

It is important that the two lists might be not of the same size.

I was trying to use dictionaries but could not figure it out. I am happy to use numpy, pandas or any other tools to get that merger.

Comment: Adapting the solution from the link above: `collections.Counter(dict(L1)) + collections.Counter(dict(L2))`. There's probably a way to skip converting lists to `dict`s first. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/11290092/2301450

Comment: What do you know about the two lists? Are they both definitely sorted? Could there be "gaps" in the middle where an item is in one list but not in the other? Are you sure that each item is a list of two integers? And so on.

Comment: the "duplicate" question is about  combining dicts, not lists

Comment: @ Rory Daulton So sorting should not be a problem since you could do that before hand. Gaps in the middle is definitly a possilbe case. Yes each item in the list has two integers, but it would be interesting if you have more than 2, however all the lists that are merged will have the same amount of items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) on both lists and simply *sum* them:

```
from collections import Counter

L1 = [[100, 1], [101, 2]]
L2 = [[100, 3], [101, 4], [102, 5]]

L_merge = (Counter(dict(L1)) + Counter(dict(L2))).items()
print(list(L_merge))
# [(100, 4), (101, 6), (102, 5)]
```

Comment: This works great, just a quick follow up: why does `list(L_merge)` produces tupples instead of lists anyway to avoid it (just out of curiosity).

Comment: @valenzio The `items` method of a dictionary produces a  list of tuples. You can use a list comprehension to cast the tuples into lists.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use a for loop:

```
L_merge = L2
for i in len(L1):
    L_merge[i][-1] += L1[i][-1]
```

The one caveat is that this only works if L2 is the longer of the 2 lists

Comment: Yes that works, I guess you could check in advance which of the lists is longer, but it seems rather cumbersome

Answer (score 0):

```
L1=[[100, 1], [101, 2]]
L2=[[100, 3], [101, 4], [102, 5]]

d = {}
for a,b in L1+L2:
  d[a] = d.get(a,0) + b
L_merge = [[k,v] for k,v in d.items()]

print(L_merge)
```